# Is it possible to add a class from another package to an existing jar file using ant?

Tags: java, jar, ant

I have an existing jar file that has three classes (Car,Home,Agency) that are in same package and same jar file. Now I have created another class Car in another package (contains extra code) and I need to update my jar by adding this class (and deleting the first Car.class).

How can I do that using ant build?

I have tried this code ant but it only delete all my classes and add a package too

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project default="makejar" name="Test" basedir=".">

    <property name="src" location="../src/pack2" />
    <property name="class" location="../class" />
    <property name="build.dir" location="../bin" />
    <!-- delete existing dir-->
     <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
      </target>
    <!--create new dir-->
    <target name="makedir">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
      </target>
    <!-- Target for compiling the java code-->
        <target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
            <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build.dir}" >
            </javac>
            <echo message="Compile Ok" />                      
        </target>
    
    <!-- Defualt target to run all targets-->
      <target name="mainTarget" depends="compile">
        <description>Main target</description>
        
      </target>
    <target name ="makejar" description="Create a jar for the HelloWorld project" depends="mainTarget">
         <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
         <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/classes"/>
         <jar jarfile="${build.dir}/HelloWorld.jar" basedir="${build.dir}" update="true">
         </jar>
        <echo message="UPDATE OK" />                   

       </target>
</project>

And now I have this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQyTV.png)

But I need all the classes not to be in a folder

I also tried this :

<target name="UpdateJar" depends="Compile"> 
  <exec executable="java path"> 
    <arg value="-uf"/> 
    <arg value="$Sample.jar"/>
    <arg value="${Path}"/> 
    <arg value="Test.class"/> 
 </exec> 
</target>
```

Comment: You need to add the source path of the new `Car` class and remove the old one.

Comment: How ? I tried this but its not working :

<target name="UpdateJar" depends="Compile">
  <exec executable="java path">
   <arg value="-uf"/>
   <arg value="$Sample.jar"/>
   <arg value="${Path}"/>
   <arg value="Test.class"/>
  </exec>
 </target>

Comment: I can't read that - you should have put that, commented, into your post above. It is possible to have several source dirs in the javac task (which is what needs to be done - *not* just adding a class into the jar) but why don't you just copy the 'new' class into the same source tree?

Comment: @g00se I added it to my question above, because they are in a different package sources and different project