# How Can I use this command line in Ant

Tags: java, jar, ant

I need to update my file jar using ant by using this line command : jar -uf sample.jar [path in jar file] target-file

I tried this :

```
<target name="UpdateJar" depends="Compile">
    <exec executable="java path">
        <arg value="-uf"/>
        <arg value="$Sample.jar"/>
        <arg value="${Path}"/>
        <arg value="Test.class"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

But It's not working no such file or directory

The error is the following: `(path is : X:\Jar\test ): [exec] X:\Jar\test no such file or directory [exec] Result: 1`

Comment: Can you provide us with the entire error message maybe? And can you also be a bit more specific about your question?

Comment: "java path" replace with "jar" then should work.

Comment: @Z-100   this is the error (path is : X:\Jar\test ): [exec] X:\Jar\test no such file or directory
     [exec] Result: 1

What i want is to update my Jar Sample.jar by adding the class Test.class (this class its an existing one) but my jar has a folder in it so if we extract it we have : Sample/test/(my classes) so what i want is to update my classes with Test.class to this path

Comment: @JaiPrakash i have an error : 
 Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program Sample.jar" (in directory  CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: [DUPLICATE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75594506/is-it-possible-to-add-a-class-from-another-package-to-an-existing-jar-file-using)

Comment: As I said in the original question, why don't you simply compile that class into the project?

Comment: Because it is in diffrent projet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the "exec" task has an extra argument, I guess you expect to include Test.class from directory "${Path}", I would write instead

```
<target name="UpdateJar" depends="Compile">
  <exec executable="java">
    <arg value="-uf"/>
    <arg value="sample.jar"/>
    <arg value="${Path}/Test.class"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Anyway, for efficiency, knowing a jar file is just a Zip file, I recommend to just update the existing jar file (already containing META/MANIFEST.MF and some classes) with Apache Ant Zip task

```
<zip destfile="sample.jar" update="true">
  <fileset dir="${Path}" includes="Test.class"/>
</zip>
```

But I guess you also expect to preserve package structure in jar file, which requires your "java" exec to run with proper current working directory. My alternative with zip is then more obvious

```
<zip destfile="sample.jar" update="true">
  <fileset dir="${Path}" includes="your/package/Test.class"/>
</zip>
```

Comment: For the path it's the package that is already in my jar so I tried to add a line command but it didn't work.
Instead i tried to do : unzip jar --> copy class into path --> create jar. It worked